# how can i reference $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in a .htaccess file?

Tags: php, apache

How can i reference the document root from within an htaccess file?

ie:

i currently have

```
php_value auto_prepend_file  C:/wamp/www/hf_latest_desktop/prepend.php
```

but i would like

```
php_value auto_prepend_file  **AUTO_DOC_ROOT**prepend.php
```

where '**AUTO_DOC_ROOT**' the root path

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot. Apache configuration files do not support this.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need to have an absolute path if the file in question is in PHP's [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php)