# Include a file to all php files recursively

Tags: php

I have this file that I want to run first before each PHP file. How can I achieve that? Now, I only use a classic php way.

```
run_me_first.php
```

and I want to tinclude it in my all of my PHP file. Besides putting it manually, is there a way not doing it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it with an .htaccess file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/file/run_me_first.php"
```

If it's a free FTP, they might have some restrictions on what settings you can alter.

Comment: Please check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343895/how-can-i-reference-serverdocument-root-in-a-htaccess-file). You may use `set_include_path`, and thus, you would only need `run_me_first.php`.

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved by using a require or include function to include the file in each of your php files. You haven't provided a great deal of information, so any response I can offer will be broad and may not pay to your particular needs.

Comment: Yes. I've done copy+paste-ing it in all of my PHP files (at the very top) But just wondering if is there a way of not doing copy+paste-ing it?

Answer (score 1):

I think You have an header file. If You dont't have then You create an **header.php** . Then include all Your files **(.php , .js)** which You want to include in all Your php files. Then You need to only include the **header.php** in the above of all Your php file.

Then this **header.php** will automatically include all Your required files. 
This will reduce time and also will reduce the probability of error. This is the process which I used to follow in all of my project.